# Infopath send email different view

Tags: infopath

I'm unable to send second view via email despite I have following rules placed. It always sends default view in the email.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem. I don't know why it does this when switching views but I do have a workaround.

Simply put I create section and put my tables I want to show in the email into the newly created section. Then I create a field with a default of 0. Add a formatting rule to the section to hide when 0. Add a rule at the button to set the hide field to 1.

Do the same for the tables you want to hide upon submission. Add a formatting rule to the tables you want hidden in the email to hide when "hide field" = 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually I'm using this workaround. InfoPath has an issue of switching views before email. In InfoPath 2010, I'm receiving a blank view when I open the email.

check this: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/16302.aspx